# Why does flexdashboard sidebar resize instead of all the columns?

Tags: r, shiny, flexbox

I have a flex dashboard with multiple tab. On one of the tabs, the sidebar resizes when I resize the whole windows and not the plots. I don't want this to happen but can't figure out why. Has anyone had this before?

[image]

Comment: May be because of long text. Try splitting it with `<BR>`

Comment: I've taken that line out and it still behaves the same. The other thing that's strange is the background colour of then sidebar: it's grey not blue. Have you seen that before?

Comment: Sorry I can't help without a reproducible example

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have just figured it out through elimination. I was calling Column {.sidebar}----- then imported some data in a code chunk before then sliders' chunk. Bizarre reason to cause a problem but if I put the data import in the same code chunk as the sliders it works fine.

Comment: Good to know you solved your issue! Reducing the code to make minimal reproducible example often help solving the issue